# Single word answer cipher 1

Tags: visual, cipher

DPOHS BUVMB UJPOT UIFGJ STUIB MGJTX IBUJT MFGU:

```
   U
  TOB
PD  EB
 QL C Z
 TTF   U
 LU XI  P
 B   F O
  U SOL
   V
```

[image]

Hint 1:

> GJOEM POHFS UIBO UISFF BOEBO EUPHF UUISFF MPOHM FGU!!

As this is my first puzzle, I greatly welcome feedback.

Comment: *Really* hoping that MGJTT should be MGJTX

Comment: Great spot you are right. Should be MGJTX. I made i by hand so that is why there are errors

Comment: Do people want a hint? Or should I wait a little longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still partial.
I think I have most of the solution but haven't managed to find the second half of the "single word answer" yet.

The initial string:

> Is just a simple Caesar cipher (ROT1), giving:
>  CONGR ATULA TIONS THEFI RSTHA LFISW HATIS LEFT
>  Or "Congratulations, the first half is what is left"
>  The first half of what? Hmm...

The grid of letters and the red lines:

> We have a sparse 9x9 grid containing 29 letters, and a set of red lines through a 5x5 grid.
>  Those lines visit a total of 29 points, which is unlikely to be a coincidence, so can we find a way to cover the grid with the lines so that we hit every letter once?

> First, let's label the lines for ease of reference:
>   [image: Grid of red lines with a number assigned to each]

> Look at the U in the first row. Only lines 3, 5 and 7 have a single highest point.
>  Line 3 doesn't work as it misses letters after UB.
>  If we use line 7, then there is then no way to cover the O in row 2.
>  So must use line 5, covering TUBOE.

> What next?
>  Let's take those letter out of the grid and see what we have left:
>
> ```
>     .
>    ...
>  PD  .B
>   QL C Z
>   TTF   U
>   LU XI  P
>   B   F O
>    U SOL
>     V
> ```
>
> Now, the B in row 3 gives us almost the same situation, and this time only line 7 is possible, covering CBZ.

> That leaves:
>
> ```
>     .
>    ...
>  PD  ..
>   QL . .
>   TTF   U
>   LU XI  P
>   B   F O
>    U SOL
>     V
> ```
>
> And again we have an isolated letter (the U in row 5) that can only be covered by line 3 - covering LOPU.

> That leaves:
>
> ```
>     .
>    ...
>  PD  ..
>   QL . .
>   TTF   .
>   LU XI  .
>   B   F .
>    U SO.
>     V
> ```
>
> We can continue in a similar manner from the bottom of the grid, where only line 2 can cover the V in row 9. (Covers UVSO.)

> That leaves:
>
> ```
>     .
>    ...
>  PD  ..
>   QL . .
>   TTF   .
>   LU XI  .
>   B   F .
>    . ...
>     .
> ```
>
> The B in row 7 can only be covered by line 1, covering TLBUF

> That leaves:
>
> ```
>     .
>    ...
>  PD  ..
>   QL . .
>   .T.   .
>   .. XI  .
>   .   F .
>    . ...
>     .
> ```
>
> And lines 4 and 6 complete this part of the puzzle, covering IFX and TQPDL respectively.

> Combined:
>  [image: Letter grid with lines overlaid]
>
>  "Words" from the lines:
>  TLBUF UVSO LOPU IFX TUBOE TQPDL CBZ
>
>  Again, we have a ROT1 encryption, and the decryption gives us:
>  SKATE TURN KNOT HEW STAND SPOCK BAY

> We can also put the letters into the grid of lines (noting that the letters match where the lines intersect), and get:
>  [image: Grid of lines with letters overlaid]
>
>  In text form:
>
> ```
>  T U F S O
>  L U V X I
>  B U P D F
>  T O B Q L
>  L C E Z T
> ```
>
> Or with the ROT1 decryption:
>
> ```
>  S T E R N
>  K T U W H
>  A T O C E
>  S N A P K
>  K B D Y S
> ```
>
> Which also contains several words:
>  stern, stops/spots, snap/pans, known, tuck, ruts

New hint (updated)!:

> The hint:
>  "GJOEM POHFS UIBO UISFF BOEBO EUPHF UUISFF MPOHM FGU!!"
>
>  Can be decrypted with the now familiar ROT1 to give:
>  FINDL ONGER THAN THREE ANDAN DTOGE TTHREE LONGL EFT!!
>
>  Or "Find longer than three and 'and' to get three long left".
>
>  Which sounds like we are meant to find all the four/five (longer than three) letter words in the grid, and "and", and the unused letters will give use a three-letter word.
>  We can find the following four/five letter words:
>  stern, stops, known, snap, ruts, tuck and bach.
>
>  Removing those from the grid, and an "and" gives us:
>  [image: Grid of letters with found words and remaining letters marked]
>
>  Now, the first encrypted sentence told us that "the first half is what is left".
>  And what we have left is **KEY**.
>  So the first half is **KEY**. What could the second half be?

Feedback as requested (spoilered for spoiler reasons):

> This puzzle doesn't seem to have got a lot of attention, but I found it interesting to solve with a couple of satisfying "a-ha" moments. (I'm unsure if there is more to do, as I still seem to be missing a second half.)
>  I think maybe a different title/tagging could have helped here, as a lot of cipher puzzles that appear here are low-effort reposts of content found elsewhere, rather than original and interesting puzzles.
>
>  The first part, using the grids of letters and lines was novel, and initially there was no obvious way to use them. The "a-ha" moment for me was spotting that the lines covered 29 points in total, matching the number of letters. From there I started looking for ways to combine them, which led fairly quickly to initial seven words.
>
>  I then sat and stared at those words for a while, failing to find something meaningful. Overlaying them on the line grid (in hindsight, an obvious thing to try) and discovering we now had something that looked like a wordsearch was pleasing. I was quite impressed that you had found a way to dissect the wordsearch grid into a set of seven other words covering every square leading to this construction.
>
>  From here, I think things went a bit awry. The "hide an answer in the unused letters of a wordsearch grid" is a reasonably well-known trick, but in this case I can't see how to get to the desired answer without the additional hint. (The solution requires taking "and" from the grid, but if you include three-letter words, "ewe" takes out the "e" required for the intended solution.)
>  But this is only a minor flaw in an otherwise enjoyable and inventive puzzle. I'll be interested to see what else you come up with.

Comment: Very close, Sorry I made an error in the clue originally. I will fix the error. I should proofread things before I post them,

Comment: Very Good. The first half was makeing the wordsearch and the second half was solving it a finding the gaps. So Your answer was correct. Thanks for the Feedback

Answer (score 2):

**Incomplete answer, but I think I've made some progress**

The first part is

> Encoded in ROT25

Which translates to

> CONGR ATULA TIONS THEFI RSTHA LFISW HATIS LEFT:

It seems to make sense as

> CONGRATULATIONS THE FIRST HALF IS WHAT IS LEFT

Although I'm unsure how that relates to the next part

> I assume the letters will be encoded in the same way, but I'll need to work out the order first. I try overlaying the letters to the lines pattern

> [image: Overlay]

But I can't make any sense of that, because

> Most of the lines/corners seem to point to blank spaces

Comment: FYI, the image was edited by me (hopefully, correctly). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSK0D.jpg) is the original image. Edit: ok, I found one error in the second string (and corrected).

Comment: I think it's a bit soon for an answer that is this partial. I have a partial answer that gets a few steps further than this that I was holding off posting because the question is only a day old.

Comment: Don't worry the image is fine :-)

Comment: @fljx sorry, I was unaware of that etiquette, I encourage anyone who agrees with you to downvote, if the answer gets downvoted to a negative I will delete it